# How to add all the values of a map without using recurrsion or var

Tags: scala

I want to add all the values in a map without using var or any mutable structures. I have tried to do something like this but it doens't work:

```
val mymap = ("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
    val sum_of_alcohol_consumption = 
    for ((k,v) <- mymap ) yield (sum_of_alcohol_consumption += v)
```

I have been told that I can use .sum on a list
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Your Map is not a Map, is that an accident?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.values` function of a Map to return an Iterable List of its values (all of the Integers) and then call the `.sum` function on that:

```
val myMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val sum = myMap.values.sum
println(sum) // Outputs: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent answer to the more elegant use of `sum` is to use a `fold` operation. `sum` is implemented in a manner similar to this:

```
val myMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val sumAlcoholConsumption = myMap.values.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

`values` returns a sequence of only the values in the map. The first `foldLeft` argument is the zero value (think of it as the initial value for an *accumulator* value) for the operation. The second argument is a function that adds the current value of the accumulator to the current element, returning the sum of the two values - and it is applied to each value in turn. That said, `sum` is a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

To get the only values of map, it provides a function values which will return iterable,we can directly appy sum function to it.

```
scala> val mymap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
mymap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> mymap.values.sum
res7: Int = 3
```